# Add custom complication data source to Samsung watch face

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-complication, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I created a Wear OS complication data source that exposes `SHORT_TEXT` and `LONG_TEXT`. The complication works correctly in the emulator with the built-in watch faces. When I deploy the app to the Samsung Watch 4 running Wear OS 3.5, the complication does not show up as a possible data source to add to a watch face slot.

Is there another step required to expose a custom complication to watch faces on Samsung Watch 4?